# magento migrate:settings fails with prefix on destination database 1.9.3.1 to 2.3.3

Tags: magento2-migration-tool

Steps.

1. Edit vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.1/config.xml for database config at old and new databases.

```xml
    <source>
        <database host="localhost" name="old_database" user="old_user" password="PaSswOrD" />
    </source>
    <destination>
        <database host="localhost" name="new_database" user="new_user" password="PaSswOrD" />
    </destination>
    <options>
        <destination_prefix>ovh</destination_prefix>
```

2. My Old database has not prefix
3. New database has prefix ovh_ (I've tried on change in settings file to **ovh_** also). Also tried `<dest_prefix>ovh_</dest_prefix>`
4. Execute magento migration tool

```
magento migrate:settings /home/tienda/tienda_develop/magento/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.1/config.xml
```

Get error:

```
[2019-11-05 16:27:15][INFO][mode: settings][stage: integrity check][step: Settings Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2019-11-05 16:27:15][ERROR]: Integrity check failed due to "core_config_data" document does not exist in the destination resource
[NOTICE]: Please check if table names uses prefix, add it to your config.xml file
[2019-11-05 16:27:15][INFO][mode: settings][stage: integrity check][step: Stores Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
```

I work over [official manual](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool-configure.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had same problem correct settings would have been

```
<dest_prefix>ovh_</dest_prefix>
```

make sure `options` does not still contain the default `<dest_prefix />`
if it does erase it